# How do I Import a class from library in databricks?

Tags: python, pyspark, python-import, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using databricks in azure to do some machine learning work and I'm trying to import a class from a specific library, but it seems to work differently than I'm used to. (I normally write python code in jupyter notebook)

I am trying to run the following in a python notebook in databricks

```py
    from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
```

I can import `statsmodels` by itself just fine, but trying to get this specific class gives me:

```
ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters'
```

It works to import classes directly in jupyter, where I am used to writing python. Moreover, even though I have imported `statsmodels`, I can't directly call any of the classes in the actual code.

Is there something special I have to do in databricks to use a specific class from a library?

Comment: did you add it under the "import library" button on the home page under "common tasks" ... this is how i add libraries on databricks community edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I tried to install `statsmodels` successfully via the left toolbar `Clusters` -> `Interactive Clusters` -> `Libraries` -> `Install New` -> `PyPI`, but got the same issue as yours.

Then I restarted my cluster and created a notebook to install it via `%sh`, as the figure below.

[image]

```
%sh
/databricks/python/bin/pip install -U statsmodels
```

It works without any issue.

Note: It's a temporary solution for installing. If you restart the cluster, the `statsmodels` installed module will disappear. So you have to run the command first to install `statsmodels` after restart the attached cluster.

Comment: This works! Can you help me understand what is going on here? What is %sh doing?

Comment: @justin.cherveny The `%sh` line makes the below code in a cell to run in Linux shell, not in Python interpreter default.

Answer (score 1):

It seems barely documented, but note that one can load a notebook as a library.

Having your library notebook named *"mylib"* as

```
def foobar():
    print("woohoo")
```

if you execute it in another notebook with (assuming it’s in the same directory)

```
%run ./mylib
```

you can access to its functions :

```
foobar()
```