# How to develop Python Library in DataBricks without packaging and installing after every single change?

Tags: databricks

For simplicity, say I have 2 Python scripts. 1 is main, 1 is lib. My question is how can I test my lib in main without needing to build the lib and installing it every single time?

Single file can be done easily as answered here ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/67280018/18105234 ). What about I have nested library?

The idea is to perform development in DataBricks like in a Jupyter Lab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Use `%run` ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html)) to include the "library" notebook into "main" notebook. You need to re-execute that `%run` cell.  Full example of this approach could be found in [this file](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/unit-tests/test_with_percent_run.py).
2. Use new functionality of [Databricks Repos](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html) called [arbitrary files](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html#enable-support-for-arbitrary-files-in-databricks-repos) - in this case, your library code should be in the Python file, together with corresponding `__init__.py` (right now you can't use notebooks), and then you include it as a "normal" Python package using `import` command.  To automatically reload changes from package you need to use special magic commands, as it's shown in [another example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo/blob/master/unit-tests/test_with_arbitrary_files.py):

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

The 2nd approach has more advantages, as it allows to take the code, and, for example, build a library from it, or apply more code checks, that aren't possible with notebooks out of box.

P.S. [My repository](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo) shows full example of how to use Databricks Repos and perform testing of the code in notebooks from CI/CD pipeline